# Squid Proxy Splash Page based on Subnet

Tags: proxy, squid

I am trying to use the Splash page feature that squid has, but I am trying to have it used only on certain subnet. I cannot figure out a way to use two ACLs to do this.

I have the following in my **squid3.conf** file

```
external_acl_type sessions ttl=60 concurrency=100 %SRC /usr/lib/squid3/squid_session -t 7200 -b /tmp/squidcache/sessions.db
acl guests external sessions src 192.168.200.0/24
acl trusted 192.168.1.0/24

deny_info http://192.168.200.5/splash.html guests
http_access deny !guests
```

This does present the splash page, but to both networks.

Has anyone run into this before?

Cheers,

Jim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add extra condition to `acl guests` this way — each squid ACL may have only a single type (you may implement “or” logic with multiple `acl` lines for the same ACL, but not “and”). Extra parameters on the `acl NAME external TYPE ...` line are actually appended to the command line of the external helper.

Also you have a syntax error on the next line (the `src` keyword is missing), but the `trusted` acl is not used in your config snippet anyway.

The proper way to write these rules is to add a separate ACL for the IP range, and use multiple ACLs in the `http_access` line:

```
external_acl_type sessions ttl=60 concurrency=100 %SRC /usr/lib/squid3/squid_session -t 7200 -b /tmp/squidcache/sessions.db

acl guests_ip src 192.168.200.0/24
# can add more "acl guests_ip src ..." here

acl guests_sessions external sessions

deny_info http://192.168.200.5/splash.html guests_sessions
http_access deny guests_ip !guests_sessions
```